# Error - 11750 TwiML response body too large

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

Hi i have integrated twilio in application. In twilio every thing is working fine for me. But once the call ended am getting [Error - 11750
TwiML response body too large](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11750). Here what i have did from my end.

```
def connect
 twiml1 = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
   r.Say "You have joined the conference."
   r.Dial do |d|
    d.Conference "#{conference_title} #{call.id}",
     waitUrl: " ",
     muted: "false",
     startConferenceOnEnter: "true",
     endConferenceOnExit: "true",
     maxParticipants: 5
    end
   end
  render xml: twiml1.to_xml
end
```

Once the conference ended am doing some payment related to application requirement.

```
def call_status
if params["CallStatus"] == "completed"
  request_call = RequestCall.find { |c| c.caller_sids.include?(params["CallSid"])}
  if request_call.present?
    #save call logs
    call_log = CallLog.new(called: params[:Called], tostate: params[:CallerCountry], callercountry: params[:CallerCountry], callerzip: params[:CallerZip],
      direction: params[:Direction], timestamp: params[:Timestamp], callbacksource: params[:CallbackSource], callerstate: params[:CallerState],
      tozip: params[:ToZip], sequencenumber: params[:SequenceNumber], callsid: params[:CallSid], to: params[:To], calledzip: params[:CalledZip],
      calledcity: params[:CalledCity], tocountry: params[:ToCountry], apiversion: params[:ApiVersion], callstatus: params[:CallStatus], duration: params[:Duration],
      from: params[:From], callduration: params[:CallDuration], accountsid: params[:AccountSid], calledcountry: params[:CalledCountry], callercity: params[:CallerCity],
      caller: params[:Caller], fromcountry: params[:FromCountry], tocity: params[:ToCity], fromcity: params[:FromCity], calledstate: params[:CalledState], fromzip: params[:FromZip],
      fromstate: [:FromState], user_id: request_call.user_id, expert_id: request_call.expert_id, request_call_id: request_call.id)
      call_log.save
    #check caller length
    if request_call.call_ended == false && request_call.call_id_length == true
      # Check estimate time with total duration
      if request_call.estimated_time.to_i == call_log.duration.to_i
        release_payment = request_call.release_full_payment
      elsif request_call.estimated_time.to_i < call_log.duration.to_i
        make_payment = request_call.release_full_payment
        express_item_id = request_call.express_item_id
        extra_time = call_log.duration.to_i - request_call.estimated_time.to_i
        pending_amount = request_call.price_to_pay(extra_time)
        second_item = request_call.express_item(pending_amount)
        if second_item.code == 200
          express_payment = request_call.release_express_payment
        end
        render json: {status: true}
      elsif request_call.estimated_time.to_i > call_log.duration.to_i
        remaining_duration = request_call.estimated_time.to_i - call_log.duration.to_i
        refund_amount = request_call.price_to_pay(remaining_duration)
        refund = request_call.refund_partial_amount(refund_amount)
        release_fund = request_call.release_full_payment
        render json: {status: true}
      end
      request_call.transition_to!(:completed)
      request_call.update(twilio_allocated_number: nil, twilio_access_code: nil, call_ended: true)
    elsif request_call.call_ended == true && request_call.call_id_length == true
      render json: {status: true}
    elsif request_call.call_ended == false && request_call.call_id_length == false
      #make payment
      request_call.transition_to!(:completed)
      request_call.update(twilio_allocated_number: nil, twilio_access_code: nil, call_ended: true, single_user: true)
      render json: {status: true}
    end
  else
    render json: {status: false}
  end
else
  render json: {status: false}
end
```

end

I don't know what i have did wrong in this. Please advice me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the nature of our system where processing is so distributed it will take a bit longer to calculate price and duration for calls, so I'd hold off for at least 30 seaconds after the call is complete, particularly during peaks of high volume.

Support recommends to use GET Requests to the REST API to pull this information into your system, instead of trying to do this in [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml). You won't run into size limitation and you won't pull null values for the fields that require processing like price, duration, status, etc.

Comment: Hi Megan Speir, thanks for your replay. But the issue is from my side. The URL which i have given is wrong. so that i got that issue.